# SQLAlchemy: partially specified relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, ddl

I am trying to describe with SQLAlchemy a relationship that exists in a legacy SQL schema. I translated the schema to:

```py
class Lang(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tblLang"
    id = Column("ID", Integer, primary_key=True)
    # ...

class ItemName(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tblItemName"
    # ItemName has a composite primary key
    id = Column("ID", Integer, primary_key=True)
    lang_id = Column("Lang", Integer, ForeignKey("Lang.id"), primary_key=True)
    name = Column("Name", String)

class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tblItem"
    id = Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True)
    inventory = Column("Inventory", Integer)
    # item_name_id specifies only part of the table
    # relationship
    item_name_id = Column("ItemNameID", Integer, ForeignKey("tblItemName.ID"))
    # lang_id should come from outside the database:
    # a user preference stored in a configuration file
    # or a session cookie, etc.
    item_name = relationship(???)
```

That is, we have a known set of languages. For each item there may be an item-name in one or more languages, but the `lang_id` we should choose will be given by an outside parameter.

I wish to be able to create a query object that has this value set before the query execution.

My question is: **What should I put instead of the `???` in the code above to be able to create such a query, and how should I specify the `lang_id` prior to execution time?**

---

Edit:

Per [@sanyash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9609843) comment, below: here is a sample query I hope to be able to get:

```sql
SELECT tblItemName.Name, tblItem.Inventory
FROM tblItem 
  LEFT JOIN tblTiemName 
    ON tblItemName.ID = tblTiem.NameID 
    AND tblItem.Lang = :lang
```

with `:lang` already set to `2` (gotten from user preferences)

When writing something like:

```py
query = session.query(Item).with_entities([
    Iten.c.item_name.name, 
    Item.c.inventory
])
```

Answer (score 3):

As to the `relationship` definition, you could simply use a custom `primaryjoin` condition. *See [Specifying Alternate Join Conditions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/join_conditions.html#specifying-alternate-join-conditions) for the documentation.*

```
relationship(
    ItemName,
    uselist=False,
    primaryjoin=f"and_(Item.item_name_id==ItemName.id, ItemName.lang_id=={LANG_ID})",
)
```

As to the when when the desired `lang_id` become available to your application, you could simply define (or redefine) the `relationship` long after the model definition and completely outside of the `Item` model mapping:

```
# ....
# now define/assign the relationship once the LANG_ID is known

LANG_NAME = "English"
LANG_ID = session.query(Lang).filter(Lang.name == LANG_NAME).one().id
print(LANG_ID, LANG_NAME)

Item.item_name = relationship(
    ItemName,
    uselist=False,
    primaryjoin=f"and_(Item.item_name_id==ItemName.id, ItemName.lang_id=={LANG_ID})",
)
```

*However, if the language is configured per user (logged in), you might need to use even later binding, or storing the Language setting in the session context, for example.*

In any event, you could then construct the desired query as below:

```
q = (
    session
    .query(ItemName.name, Item.inventory)
    .select_from(Item)
    .join(ItemName, Item.item_name)
)

for res in q:
    print(res)
```

Comment: A more involved, but potentially better solution might be to implement the custom query. See [FilteredQuery](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/wiki/FilteredQuery) recipy.

Comment: Note that in the last snippet, `.join(ItemName, Item.item_name)` can probably be replaced with just `.join(ItemName)` as it already has enough information (foreign key + relationship) to figure out the ON clause by itself.

Comment: Another `relationship` tip here (pun intended) is to use strings rather than refer to the class itself e.g. `relationship('ItemName', ...)`. This is especially helpful when each ORM is placed in its own file, and suddenly you have ORM A importing ORM B for some query in a `classmethod`. This is avoidable by utilizing the relationships rather than directly referring to the respective ORM classes.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for your sample query with your code as is, without defining the relationship:

```py
res = session.query(
    ItemName.name,
    Item.inventory,
).select_from(Item).outerjoin(ItemName).filter(
    ItemName.lang_id == 2
)
```

(because only the foreign key is needed here, which you've defined)

---

One thing you *could* do with a `relationship` is:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased
from sqlalchemy.sql import func


class Item(Base):
    ...
    item_name = relationship('ItemName')

    @classmethod
    def get_lang_total_inventory_dict(cls):
        """Returns {lang_id: total_inventory}"""
        item_name = aliased(cls.item_name)

        res = session.query(
            item_name.lang_id,
            func.sum(cls.inventory),
        ).select_from(cls).join(item_name).group_by(
            item_name.lang_id
        )

        return dict(res)
```

Notice how `???` was replaced with `'ItemName'` rather than `ItemName`.
This allows to use `ItemName` in the query without directly referring to its class.
Which prevents circular imports, a real pain when each ORM sits in its own file.

There are [other things you can do with relationships](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/stable/orm/tutorial.html#working-with-related-objects) as well.

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING: this is a workaround and might not be optimal or even correct**

I wasn't able to find the magic incantation that will make relationship do what I want. Instead I can write a workaround:

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property, hybrid_method


class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tblItem"
    id = Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True)
    inventory = Column("Inventory", Integer)

    @hybrid_method
    def item_name(self, lang):
        return ItemName.query.filter(
            ItemName.id == self.id,
            ItemName.lang_id == lang
        )

    @hybrid_property
    def item_names(self):
        return ItemName.query.filter(ItemName.id == self.id)
```

I then can use it like:

```py
item_names = Item.get(123).item_names.all()
item_klingon_name = Item.get(123).item(KLINGON_LANG_ID).one()
```

I am fully aware this is not a proper solution, and it does not do eager loading. I am not even sure if I use [`@hybrid_method` and `@hybrid_property`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/hybrid.html) correctly in this context.

I post this answer in the hope it can benefit some use-cases, but will gladly accept other solutions, preferably ones that use `relationship`.

Comment: Dear Chen, please see my comment to the accepted(?) answer on how this usage could get messy very quickly.